# Shortcut to close Notepad++'s console

Tags: console, notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I close the Notepad++'s console through hot key?

[image]

If I press <kbd>F3</kbd> in the console window, the bottom section pops up. But having the "Hide toggled Console" box checked does not seem to be doing anything.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this console part of a Notepad++ plugin? If yes then please specify the exact name of the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (the symbol to the left of the 1 on US keyboards) to *toggle* console window (i.e., show / hide). You can also click the "Show Console" button on the toolbar, shown below.

[image: Screenshot of Notepad++ showing console close button]

Answer (score 0):

Goto Macro > Modify Shortcut/Delete macro 
and

You can set your own shortcut key for Show Console